# How to solve the following Oracle NoSQL error (The query doesn't contain the variable)?

Tags: oracle-nosql

I have the following error when trying to do a query using the API calls

```
{
  "code": "InvalidParameter",
  "message": "The query doesn't contain the variable: id"
}
```

Please, ci-below the payload and the call executed

```
oci-curl nosql.eu-frankfurt-1.oci.oraclecloud.com post ./request.json "/20190828/query"  | jq
[opc@instance-dev ~]$ cat request.json
{
  "compartmentId": "ocid1.xxxxxx"
, "statement":     "DECLARE $id LONG; SELECT * FROM test_table where id > $id"
, "variables" : {"id":"10"}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables must be the same as in DECLARE statement including the $ and same types.

In you case, the good name for the variable is $id and not id

`"variables" : {"$id":10}`